# Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter on PL/pgSQL function

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I've created postgresql function on DB and defined trigger for after update on table.
Postgresql has a current_setting() option and in the function i need to check one specific parameter.

On DBeaver sql editor it works fine with the following lines;

```
BEGIN;
SELECT set_config('myapp.my_unique_id', 1, true);
    
update my_table set name = 'test' where my_table_id =1234;
COMMIT;
```

My question is; how can i set this configuration parameter via hibernate - springboot application ?
This parameter will update dynamically in the application before each DB transaction (insert-update-delete).I mean the value of the parameter will be different each time.

For now, when I try to update my_table on DB, it gets the following error;

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3449)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.updateOrInsert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3311)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.update(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3723)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:201)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1360)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:451)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3210)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2378)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:447)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:534)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "myapp.my_unique_id"
  Where: SQL statement "select
    current_setting('myapp.my_unique_id')"
PL/pgSQL function my_function() line 49 at SQL statement
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2468)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2211)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:309)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:446)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:370)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:149)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:124)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
```

Here is the sample function;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_function()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    declare 
     my_id numeric := 0;
    begin
       select current_setting('myapp.my_unique_id') into my_id;
        raise notice 'my_id: %', my_id;
        
        update my_table set row_id = my_id where  my_table_id = 124;
    
     RETURN NEW;
    END;     
    $function$
;

CREATE TRIGGER my_function
after UPDATE ON my_table
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_function();
```

I need this parameter for logging each DB operation and that parameter will be user_id.
I may be proceeding wrong, if you have a different idea, we can take into account.

Thank you all.

Answer (score -1):

Use

```
SELECT current_setting('myapp.my_unique_id', TRUE);
```

Then you will get `NULL` instead of an error message if the parameter doesn't exist.

Comment: This may be a solution to override the error message, but this parameter will be required.

Comment: Well, then set it.

Comment: Well, what do you expect if you don't set the parameter? You can either get an error or nothing.